# How do I set up a dedicated TFS build server in TFS 2018?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

We are using a server running Windows Server 2012 R2 for our TFS work item management and source control.

But we want to set up a dedicated Build server.
We are running TFS 2018 Update1.

I've downloaded the latest available Build agent and ran the script 'config.cmd' from the dedicated Build Server.

In previous versions of TFS you were at least supposed to run the TFS Installation Wizard if I'm correct to configure the Build Service. But this changed since TFS 2015.

But where can you see that my dedicated server (that I used to run config.cmd) is actually used for executing the Build process?

I cannot really find information on how to install and configure multiple servers for running TFS.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know running the config.cmd is enough. The machine where the script is executed will then register with the server instance - during the configuraiton you had to specify the TFS Server URL right?

On the Server side, you can go to the Agent Pools (where you initially downloaded the Agent Configuration). After clicking on the Agent Pools on the left-hand side you should see all Agents registered to that Queue. To which Queue your agent belongs was as well specified during the configuration on the agent itself as part of the config.cmd.

[image: Agent Configuration]

If you want to add more agents, you can simply run the config.cmd on other machine and register your agent with the same server instance. It is even possible to have more than one agent on the same physical hardware if you want that.

Comment: Is it correct if I would say that you can create multiple pools, but that you need to register an agent within that pool. And the agent that is registered, runs on the machine that is was registered from?

Thanks

Comment: Yes exactly, thats true. So the machine that runs the config script will be registered as an agent.